# Adding sound in a web site

Tags: web, audio

How can I add sound to a web site . I don't want to show .swf player in the page .music should play in the background

Comment: Its a client requirement.I have to.And in this case they are right:-)

Comment: Nothing makes me close a website faster than sound playing.  It's just wrong on all levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<audio>` tag, but check if that is supported in all browsers you are interested in. If not, you can use an invisible swf.

But I'd recommend you not to putting background sound into the site, it tends to be really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the div element inside which you put the swf object, in the page. Set the display state to **none** instead of **block**. Something Like :

```
<div style="display:none;">

<Your swf object>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's old but it works.

[9 Versions to play a sound on a web page](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm)

I've used version 8 "Using a Java Applet called from JavaScript" for firefox and IE8.